# How to iterate over folders stored in a MAPIFolder object?

Tags: c++, com, outlook-addin, atl

I'm working on a Outlook Add-in developed in COM/ATL/C++ and I want to iterate over all subfolders of a particular Outlook folder, which is passed off as a [MAPIFolder object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder_members.aspx).

According to Microsoft's docs, a MAPIFolder object includes a [Folders property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.folders.aspx) whjich consists of a [Folders collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.folders.aspx) which represent all the available Outlook folders in a specific subset at one level of the folder tree.  Yet, I haven't found any reference on how to iterate over these collections.  Microsoft's docs are virtually nonexistent, and although there are examples covering similar features in C#, such as [MS DevCenter How to: Get a Default Folder and Enumerate Its Subfolders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184610.aspx), Microsoft does not offer any info on how to accomplish the same goal with C++.

Does anyone know how to iterate over all folders with calls to MAPIFolder and/or Folders objects?

Comment: Are you looking for MAPI documentation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/cc765775.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc815424.aspx

Comment: @SimonMourier No, he is asking how to 'develop an Outlook Add-in developed in COM/ATL/C++'. That is, using the COM API, and specifically the `Folders` object.

Comment: @user207421 - OP never answered.

Comment: @SimonMourier *I* am answering you. Read the question. Nothing there about MAP whatsoever. He mentions COM/ATL. QED.

Comment: @user207421 - I don't need your answer, if you know, answer yourself

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop (from 1 to Count). Or call `Folders.GetFirst` and use `while` loop calling `Folders.GetNext` on each iteration.